# What could cause this Object Reference error?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an intermittent error in an MVC application (.NET Framework 4.6.1, MVC 5.2.3) hosted in IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server.

It can be running along happily enough until at some point this error occurs:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.]
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetNotifcationContextProperties(Boolean& 
isReentry, Int32& eventCount) +112
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +251
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext 
context, AsyncCallback cb) 
 System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest 
wr, HttpContext context) +474
```

When this occurs, sometimes I can refresh the page and it goes away, but then I hit another page and it appears immediately again. Usually it ends up affecting all pages, for all users, and can't be resolved until I restart the app pool.

I can reproduce the problem (sometimes) if I click around the application's navigation quickly, not letting it completely load a requested page.

I can't reproduce the problem at all locally running in Visual Studio.

A Google search suggests this may be down to custom event handlers, but I have no custom event handlers in the code (I can't vouch for any NuGet packages I'm using). The global.asax.cs is very sparse, and just contains Application_Start:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Any idea on either what is causing this, or recommendations for logging I could apply that could get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Best thing to do is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  I suspect the webpage has fully loaded before you are running the page.  Probably some java is running and you need to wait before java completes.  You may want to add some delays in your code just to see where the issue is occurring and the amount of time you need to wait.

Comment: `System.Web.HttpApplication.GetNotifcationContextProperties` where the NRE happens is in Microsoft code. Which should never throw NRE. So they have a bug. It might be exposed by incorrect usage on your part, but without a good [mcve], I don't see how anyone on SO is supposed to help you work around the issue. You may have better luck engaging Microsoft by reporting their bug and seeing if they can shed light into how you ran across it.